# how to get the second class in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="nav-top">
  <ul>
      <li class="test tab1"><a href="/">test</a></li>
      <li class="tes tab2"><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li class="tes tab3"><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li class="navahead"><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li class="navahead"><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li class="new"><a href="#">test</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="subnav-content" class="tab1">hello world</div>
```

supposed  a variable like the following:

```
var tab_class = $(this).attr('class');   //this equals li
```

i want to use tab1 tab2 tab3 independently in the following code eg:

```
$("#subnav-content div." + tab_class).show();
```

the `tab_class` will get two value(test tab1). how to get rid of the test and the space?

Comment: you should extend your previous question instead of creating a new one for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tabs = tab_class.match(/(tab\d+)/g);
tab_class = (tabs) ? tabs[0] : 'none';
```

**Updated** the code to account for @Hnatt's suggestion.

With this code, if the variable `tab_class` contains a class name such as `tab1`, `tab2`, ... it will be assigned that name, otherwise it will be assigned `none`.

[Test case](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/mmdeN/)

Instead of getting rid of the `test` and the space, focus on getting the `tab1` out of that variable.

---

In addition, this is not correct:

```
$("#subnav-content div." + tab_class).show();
```

It should be

```
$("div#subnav-content." + tab_class).show();
```

Comment: You might want to check if there are any matches at all before getting first match. Because if there are none, then you will get TypeError.

Comment: @zhuanzhou: It's a regex to match any string in the format `tab` + any number. E.g. `tab1`, `tab234`, etc...

Answer (score 4):

```
tab_class.split(/\s+/).pop()
```

To get the last class.

**EDIT:** But, as [Tarun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/387387/tarun) kindly pointed out, classes may be rearranged in alphabetical order while rendering. So my vote goes for [Shef's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730633/how-to-get-the-second-class-in-jquery/6730741#6730741), but you need to check if there are any matches before dealing with it as with array.

Comment: it would probably be more robust to split on /\s+/

Comment: if you can be so sure about the structure, I'd go with `tab_class.split(/\s+/).pop();`

Comment: @zhuanzhou: it represents any amount of whitespace characters.

Comment: I wont go with a regex solution here, because a browser might render "test tab1" as "tab1 test" in DOM. Best way is to replace 'tes' with ' ' and then trim the spaces.

Comment: Thanks @Tarun, you are right. I updated my answer according to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
var tab_class = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1]
```

but its probably bad idea to hard code index ;]

Comment: if the space is large. it will not get the value.

Answer (score 1):

just a suggestion, why dont u write your code as:

```
<div class="nav-top">
  <ul>
      <li class="test tab1" id="tab1-link"><a href="/">test</a></li>
      <li class="tes tab2" id="tab2-link"><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li class="tes tab3" id="tab3-link"><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li class="navahead" id="tab4-link"><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li class="navahead" id="tab5-link"><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li class="new" id="tabx-link"><a href="#">test</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="subnav-content" class="tab1">hello world</div>
```

and then use following js:

```
...
var tab_class = $(this).attr('id');
tab_class = tab_class.replace('-link','');
...
```

the advantage here is that there wont be any JS error. performance wont suffer as we are only assigning ID to DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
 tab_class = tab_class.replace('tes ','');
```

Comment: i tested your code. the value didn't make any change. what's the replace('tes ','') meaning? thank you